# fancybox 2 on internet explorer 10 inexpected behavior with open link inside an fancybox iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am using fancybox 2 and using it to create an iframe to a URL. if my URL contains links to other pages within my site and I click them. fancy-box X button stop functioning. this works perfectly on firefox / chrome, but not on IE. in addtion, the size of the windows seems to double.

Also there is an error in IE console when clicking on the X after getting into the second link:

SCRIPT70: Permission denied 
jquery-1.9.0.js, line 3882 character 2

I do have a DOCTYPE on my html.

EDIT : this is reproduced with fancybox 2 demo , both locally or on server side.
just change the line in iframe.html (on fancybox demo) from

```
<a href="javascript:parent.jQuery.fancybox.open({href : '1_b.jpg', title : 'My title'});">Change content</a>
```

to :

```
<a href="iframe.html">Change content</a>
```

I could use the fancybox.open , however I doing a POST operation instead of standard URL redirection so I cant using fancybox.open....

Comment: hard to help without code. are you testing in a server environment? if not, you should. My guess, one of the iframes triggers a js error (IE is pickier than other browsers that may overlook little syntax errors)

Comment: I edit my post. This problem reproduced in fancybox sample demo. it doesn't seems to be a JS. seems that fancybox was aware of it because on the same it use fancybox.open instead of a direct a href. However I need to post a form...

Comment: well, I guess you are missing to specify the `type` of content like `<a href="iframe.html" data-fancybox-type="iframe">Change content</a>`

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is because of jQuery.  You will want to update from 1.9 to at least 10.1  This fixes the issue with IE.  If you can't update right away, there are a few people who found some workarounds, but I would honestly just advise moving to the newest version of jQuery.

[jQuery Blog](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/30/jquery-1-10-1-and-2-0-2-released/)

[The bug report is here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13936)

Comment: Thank you very much! After long search, upgraded to version 1.10.2 worked perfectly.